# Network Simulation using NS-3

Tags: networking, malware, ns-3

Can I simulate susceptible-infected-susceptible (SIS) model using NS-3?
I'm aiming to model malware flow using SIS and trying to simulate using NS-3.

I'm a newbie to networks, and have been searching for this since hours, going through tens of research papers but can't find anything similar.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIS implies some sort of discovery mechanism to spread the infection of a network. These discovery mechanisms typically use exploits in network capable daemons. So, to simulate SIS, you want a simulator that works at the [application level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite#Layer_names_and_number_of_layers_in_the_literature) of the network stack.

*ns-3* has some application-level capabilities, but it's mostly intended to be used to simulate the network stack below the application level. The application-level capabilities that *ns-3* does have are limited to traffic generation. Discovering the presence of a service on a Node, let alone a compromised version of a daemon, is not supported.

So, it seems like you'll need to find another simulator. I'm not sure what your options are, but depending on how complex of a simulation you want, you could just roll your own by representing the network as a graph, and infecting a susceptible node with probability `p`.